# Rotating logger in python

Tags: python, logging

EDIT: 
I want to have a logger in python which rotates on every day. 
For example following log files will be created ..

eg

```
log_20130701
log_20130702
log_20130703
log_20130704
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup the filename with the date.

```
import datetime
...
logConfig['filename'] = 'error.log_%s' % datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
...
log.dictConfig(logConfig)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was too busy in thinking about solution using built in logger. Did'nt realize that their could be other way of doing it. :)